# Casting a Type to DBSet<>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Is it possible to cast a type definition in C#? Such as the following:

```
Type t = typeof(Activity) as typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyDomain.Activity>)
```

Or trying to force a cast:

```
Type t2 = typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyDomain.Activity>) typeof(Activity);
```

I want to create a type definition `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyDomain.Activity>`

I'm doing this because I'm using reflection on my domain, trying to pull on the properties on the context, in case anyone asks.

```
// get types we are interested in IHit
var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IHit))
                         && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IHit;
// loop and cast
foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    Type t = instance.GetType()
    Type t2 = typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<t>) as typeof(t);

    // do something with type 2
}
```

Comment: [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you want to do? Cast a type as a type? What would `t` be in the end?

Comment: Sorry, even with the explanation you provide, I still can't make sense of your question. If you want to get the `Type` corresponding to `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyDomain.Activity>`, just write `typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyDomain.Activity>)`, no need to separately involve `typeof(Activity)` there.

Comment: I can't write the type name explicity because I'm using reflection to get the type value in the first place.

Comment: @wonea Now it's starting to make sense... but you didn't write that anywhere in your question.

Comment: Sorry realised I was vague, so added more to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to create a type definition `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyDomain.Activity>`

So you are actually asking `t` to be the type of `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyDomain.Activity>`. Why do you need to cast one type of another? The type `MyDomain.Activity` doesn't have to do anything with the type you are actually requesting.

This should work for you:

```
Type t = typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyDomain.Activity>)
```

If you don't have the type of `MyDomain.Activity` yet, you should use [`Type.MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 Type dbSetType = typeof(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<>);
 Type t = dbSetType.MakeGenericType(yourActivityType);
```